# Editing String Objects in a List in Python

Tags: python, list

I have read in data from a basic txt file. The data is time and date in this form "DD/HHMM" (meteorological date and time data). I have read this data into a list: time[]. It prints out as you would imagine like so: ['15/1056', '15/0956', '15/0856', .........]. Is there a way to alter the list so that it ends up just having the time, basically removing the date and the forward slash, like so: ['1056', '0956', '0856',.........]? I have already tried list.split but thats not how that works I don't think. Thanks.

Comment: `time = [s.split('/')[1] for s in time]`

Comment: you can update them by-index, but it's usually better to generate (`yield`) new members or to create a new list

Comment: @0x5453 thank you very much, as you can probably tell I am new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still learning myself and I haven't touched python in sometime, BUT, my solution if you really need one:

```
myList = ['15/1056', '15/0956', '15/0856']
newList = []

for x in mylist:
    newList.append(x.split("/")[1])

    # splits at '/'
    # returns ["15", "1056"]
    # then appends w/e is at index 1


print(newList) # for verification
```